Determine in the test the browser I want to run the playwright test
I have many tests in one file and I want to determine in each test which browser will run the test. The problem is that I am not able to determine the browsers, and the tests are failing when web runs mobile and mobile runs web
Ex:test('test1 - should run in chromium')...test('test2 - should run in mobile')...

how can I do it but still using the same file for all tests
I have read somethings but I didn't find a solution.

Please share your package.json, playwright config, sample tests and command you're currently running.

I think that tagging tests is the best way to do that.
You also have a way to Conditionally skip a group of tests.
